# Unable to use array element with Vuetify v-file-input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component that uses multiple Vuetify  **v-file-input** components

```
<v-file-input
                :accept="allowedFileTypes"
                label="Choose Attachment"
                :loading="attachmentBeingProcessed"
                name="file0" 
                id="file0"
                :error='fileSizeError[0]'
                outlined
                dense
                @change="fileSelectedForUpload(0)"
                @click:clear="removeAttachment(0)"
            ></v-file-input>
```

I want to show a particular **v-file-input** in error mode through code. However, when I set **this.fileSizeError[0] = true**, it does not put the component in error mode. However, if I use a variable (not array), as show below, it works

```
<v-file-input
                :accept="allowedFileTypes"
                  label="Choose Attachment"
                :loading="attachmentBeingProcessed"
                    name="file1" id="file1"
                    :error='fileSizeError1'
                     :error-messages = "fileSizeErrorMsg1"
                outlined
                dense
                @change="fileSelectedForUpload(1)"
                @click:clear="removeAttachment(1)"
            ></v-file-input>
```

Is there a reason that I cannot use an array element with ":error"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with assigning an array value to a prop, the problem is [changing an array index value is not reactive in Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).  As the docs explain, to get around this issue you can update your array[0] value to `true` using `$set`:

```js
this.$set(this.fileSizeError, 0, true);
```